# Getting Exceptions while trying to run Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

I have written a Spring MVC application in IntelliJ. This is the **pom.xml** for it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>com.packt</groupId>
      <artifactId>webstore</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>war</packaging>

      <name>webstore Maven Webapp</name>
      <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
      <url>http://www.example.com</url>

      <properties>
          <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
          <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
          <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
      </properties>

      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>junit</groupId>
              <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
              <version>4.11</version>
              <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
              <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
         </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>webstore</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.20.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

When I try to work with this pom.xml, I get this exception.

```
16-May-2018 12:04:00.662 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.ad
dChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apa
che.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@33723e30]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(Lifecy
cleBase.java:441)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardR
oot.java:724)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardConte
xt.java:4742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
t.java:4877)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:71
8)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:
1858)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:51
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineEx
ecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorS
ervice.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:772
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1585)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java
:308)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
se.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase
.java:424)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:36
7)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
va:966)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java
:839)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1427)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1417)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineEx
ecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorS
ervice.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
va:943)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.
java:258)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardServic
e.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.
java:770)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: inval
id LOC header (bad signature)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.ini
tInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:734)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:43
4)
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
        at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.ini
tInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:141)
        ... 45 more

16-May-2018 12:04:00.680 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.de
ployWAR Error deploying web application archive [C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\TomcatNew
\webapps\webstore.war]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.cata
lina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.web
resources.JarResourceSet@33723e30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:746)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:71
8)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:
1858)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:51
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineEx
ecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorS
ervice.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:772
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1585)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java
:308)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
se.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase
.java:424)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:36
7)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
va:966)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java
:839)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1427)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1417)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineEx
ecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorS
ervice.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
va:943)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.
java:258)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardServic
e.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.
java:770)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
```

I searched for solving this issue on Stackoverflow, and it was suggested in some of the posts to change the scope in **pom.xml** to **provided** for all dependencies except the junit one.

After I changed the pom, this **LifeCycleException** was gone. But, now whenever I tried to hit the endpoints corresponding to the **DispatcherServlet**, I got **HTTP 500 error**.  [image]

I checked these 2 posts - [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256447/http-status-500-error-instantiating-servlet-class-org-springframework-web-serv) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227395/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-servlet-dispatcherserv). I found out that because of my new POM, the **WEB-INF/lib** folder was not having the JARs/Maven Dependencies, leading to this new error. Because of this reason, I am stuck in a deadlock. I remove one error and other surfaces.

Also, I tried to put **load-on-startup** tag in **web.xml**, which in turn led to **HTTP 404**.

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**DefaultServlet-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.packt.webstore" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Controller**

```
package com.packt.webstore;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {


    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hey!");
        model.addAttribute("tagline", "Hello!");

        return "welcome";
    }

}
```

**welcome.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;
charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/
bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1> ${greeting} </h1>
            <p> ${tagline} </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

It will be great in case someone can help. Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem before, and the problem turned out to be just some corrupted jars in the local repository, try to delete .m2 folder.

Since you are using windows, this should be the path to your .m2 repo.

```
C:\Users\[username]\.m2\repository
```

Comment: Can you please explain in brief the steps to be followed? Sorry I can't find any .m2 folder in IntelliJ project explorer.

Comment: Well I tried doing that. But it didn't help. What pom do I need to use? The new one with scope as provided or the previous one?